# Application Defined Error or Object error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Could any one take a look at my code and help me find out which I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Price()

Dim ilastrow As Long

Dim i As Long

ilastrow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

For i = ilastrow To 2 Step -1

Sheets(2).Cells(i, 10).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("D2:F520"), 2, False), 0)

Sheets(2).Cells(i, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets(2).Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("D2:F520"), 3, False), 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be easier to maintain and read if you use a few variables.

Also, you can drop the `WorksheetFunction` and test the return value using `IsError()`

```
Sub Price()

Dim ilastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, v, res, rng As Range

    ilastrow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Sheets(1).Range("D2:F520")

    For i = ilastrow To 2 Step -1

        With Sheets(2).Rows(i)

            v = .Cells(4).Value

            res = Application.VLookup(v, rng, 2, False)
            .Cells(10).Value = IIf(IsError(res), 0, res)

            res = Application.VLookup(v, rng, 3, False)
            .Cells(11).Value = IIf(IsError(res), 0, res)

        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the evaluate method instead, e.g. :

```
Sheets(2).Cells(i, 10).Value = Evaluate("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",'" & Sheets(1).Name & "'!$D$2:$F$520,2,FALSE),0)")
```

Also, are you sure that Sheets(1) is the right sheet? If you have been adding/deleting sheets then the index could potentially change and that sheet may no longer exist. Where possible, you should reference the sheets name or set the worksheet to a variable and work with that instead.

For example:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("This Sheet")
Set ws2 = Sheets("That Sheet")

ws1.Cells(i, 10).Value = Evaluate("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D" & i & ",'" & ws2.Name & "'!$D$2:$F$520,2,FALSE),0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the worksheet function `IFERROR` as `Application.IfError` in VBA. Catching the error is sufficient to throw an error when used in this manner. Here is a non-destructive method of checking to see if the `VLOOKUP` will match before using it to retrieve the value.

```
Sub Price()
    Dim ilastrow As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets(2)
        ilastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = ilastrow To 2 Step -1
            .Cells(i, 10).Resize(1, 2) = 0
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(Sheets(1).Columns("D"), .Cells(i, 4).Value)) Then
                .Cells(i, 10).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("D2:F520"), 2, False)
                .Cells(i, 11).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("D2:F520"), 3, False)
                'alternate method
                '.Cells(i, 10).Resize(1, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 4).Value, Sheets(1).Range("D2:D520"), 0) + 1, 5).Resize(1, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```